# MaterialisingResponse throwing NullReferenceException in Nancy Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, nancy

I am using Visual Studio 2013 trying to build a Nancy Web Site (asp.net hosted, Razor engine and .net 4.0/4.5 tried both).  My NuGet package was updated from Nancy v0.23.1 to v0.23.2 and now I am getting this exception (see below) trying to get to any page on the site.

I did research and saw there was a similar problem with the v0.23.0 release, but docs and bug reports have this problem as resolved/closed with v0.23.1

I did check, and my `_layout.cshtml` file is in the root of the views folder and no where am I referencing the `_layout.cshtml` file other than `Layout = "_layout.cshtml"`

I pulled a copy of the Nancy code to be able to debug the source.  It looks like the `"PreExecute"` task is never hit and the ctor accesses `this.oldResponseOutput` which is null.

Has this bug re-surfaced?  Anyone else having this issue?  Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
 Nancy.Responses.MaterialisingResponse.<.ctor>b__0(Stream stream) +48
 Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHandler.SetNancyResponseToHttpResponse(HttpContextBase context, Response response) +273
 Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHandler.EndProcessRequest(Task`1 task) +279
 Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +73
 System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129
 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +22
 System.Web.AsyncStepCompletionInfo.ReportError() +16
 System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651198
 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? If not I can try to repro.

Comment: I have not found a solution, I had to put it on the back burner for a couple of days.  I will be getting back into this issue this evening.  I did start a fresh asp.net hosted razor nancy project to try and pin point what the issue was.  I did notice "other" Nuget packages were updated also which in combination could have cause the issue.  I will post my findings this evening.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what changed between 0.23.1 and 0.23.2 but having and invalid assembly named in the IRazorConfiguration class seems to have caused this. I had invalid names spaces and invalid assembly names in `GetASsemblyNames` and invalid namespaces in `GetDefaultNamespaces`.  They should have been cleaned up after a few refactorings, but why did it work in 23.1 and not 23.2.  Oh well....